# different output every 3 column

Tags: php, loops, foreach

What i am attempting to do is something like this

[Col-3][Col-3][Col-3][Col-3]

[Col-4][Col-4][Col-4]

[Col-3][Col-3][Col-3][Col-3]

I am continuing this with a foreach statement, but without luck at the moment.

Currently i'm just doing something like this.

```
$post = new mm_post();
$rows = $post->getAllPosts();
$i = 1;
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
  if ($i % 4 == 0) {
     echo "[Col-3] <br>";
  } else {
     echo "[Col-4] <br>";
  }
  $i++;
}
```

I am looking for a solution and explanation for this :)
Obviously atm it just make every 3 post [col-3] but i want it to make 4 col-3 then 3 col-4 is what i am looking for.

So I hope you guys can help me! :)

Comment: Sorry but if its remainder by 4 is 0 then why arent you printing it four time. Please correct me if i am missing something also data structure of rows would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about every 7 posts makes 2 lines...one with 4 cols and one with 3 cols:
so when the $i counter is divisible by 7 you print a < br>. Then when line element is less then 4 print *col-3*,when is 4 print *col-3* and < br> otherwise print *col-4*

```
    $post = new mm_post();
    $rows = $post->getAllPosts();
    $i = 1;
    $line=0;
    for($rows as $key => $row)
    {
        if($i-($line*7)<4)
            {
              echo "[col-3]";
            }
            else  if($i-($line*7)==4)
            {
                echo "[col-3]<br>";
            }
            else 
           { 
                echo "[col-4]";
           }

        if($i%7==0)
           {
               echo "<br>";
               $line++;
           }

            $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function alternate_slices($arr) {
    $slices = array();

    $start = 0;
    $length = 4;

    while ($start < count($arr)) {
        $slices[] = array_splice($arr, $start, $length);

        $length = (4 - $length + 3);
    }

    return $slices;
}

$arr = range(1, 20);
$sliced_arr = alternate_slices($arr);

<!-- print_r($sliced_arr);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 10
            [3] => 11
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 14
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 17
            [3] => 18
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
            [1] => 20
        )
) -->

$sliced_arr = array_map(
    function ($slice) {
        return implode("||", $slice);
    },
    $sliced_arr
);

<!-- print_r($sliced_arr);
Array
(
     [0] => 1||2||3||4
     [1] => 5||6||7
     [2] => 8||9||10||11
     [3] => 12||13||14
     [4] => 15||16||17||18
     [5] => 19||20
) -->

$sliced_arr = implode("\n", $sliced_arr);

<!-- print($sliced_arr);
1||2||3||4
5||6||7
8||9||10||11
12||13||14
15||16||17||18
19||20 -->
```

Read about:

- [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)
- [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)